# Shared Preferences in libGdx for highscore

Tags: java, android, libgdx, android-studio-3.0

I am making a mario type game and i want to save my highscore but when i restart my app highscore becomes zero.I am using libGdx and i don't know how to use shared preferences and where to write in create or render method.
I am using this code but it does not work.

```
...protected Preferences highScore(){
if (score> highScore){
prefs.putInteger("highScore",score);
this.highScore=prefs.getInteger("highScore",0);
prefs.flush():
}
return prefs;
}...
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46840077/7339411

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without more code...
I assume that when you start your game you initialize your preference object and read the current highscore? otherwise highscore would be defaulted to 0;

1. initialize your preference object. you can do that upon game creation for example.

Then in your game, whenever you update your score:

```
// When you start the game. Execute once at the beginning of each game.
Preferences prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("My Preferences");
int this.highScore=prefs.getInteger("highScore",0); 

// When you start finish the game. Execute when the player finished the game
if (score> highScore){
        prefs.putInteger("highScore",score);
        this.highScore=prefs.getInteger("highScore",0);
        prefs.flush():
}
```

Comment: Hi Julien ,I am new to android studio and i dont know how to use shared preferences.I take this code online .Can you tell me from starting what i have to do for saving my highscore.Specially where to write code?

Comment: Because i am using libgdx.Thanks for the help.

Comment: updating my answer to provide more info